# Stacking shields without headers

Tags: arduino-uno, shields

In the project I am working on, I have a limited space with which I can work. I am using an Arduino Uno with 2 Adafruit motor shields, and when I stack them using normal, female stacking headers it is too tall to fit. I thought that one way to solve this would be to lay them out side to side rather than one on top of the other. So, instead of this

```
+--------Motor shield 2 ----------+
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
+--------Motor shield 1 ----------+
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
+---------Arduino Uno ------------+
```

it would look like this

```
               -----------------------------------------Wires -------------------------------           
+---------Arduino Uno ------------+    +--------Motor shield 1 ----------+    +--------Motor shield 2 ----------+
```

Would this be possible if I were to connect all of the pins with wires, and has anyone successfully done this before?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have some success with this, but keep in mind that the longer the wire, the higher the inductance and voltage drop across the wire. Prefer to use a star topology rather than a chain topology, with the Arduino in the middle of all the shields in use.

Comment: Also you probably only need a few wires connected.  It looks like the motor shield uses 6 pins, 2 I2C pins, pins 9 and 10 (if using hobby servos), power and ground.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no problem running individual wires, and also like Craig says, only run the wires you need. For some inspiration, here's a project I did with a [bit of hand wiring](http://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=44710). And then there's [this project](http://www.ducatimonsterforum.org/index.php?topic=64324.0) with kinda epic wiring.